# Can I use App Service Certificates in Azure VM for ssl configuration

Tags: azure, ssl, playframework

I have purchased one Azure App Service Certificates in my Azure portal. I am not using any App services but the windows Virtual machine. Where I run the play framework app which needs the ssl certificate to produce https.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c5c665b5-f857-4d9e-bba3-109ba20d2de1/export-app-service-certificate-to-running-vm-so-i-can-use-it-for-https-is-there-any-way-i-can-do?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

How can I use this App service certificate into VM instance. I have tried importing the keys for manual configuration but no single documentation of Azure I found where it can confirm.

Comment: We are also looking to find a way to export the certificate with its private key from an Azure App Service Certificate so that we can use it with Hybrid Connector proxies as well as the App Services. I haven't seen anything yet.

Answer (score 2):

You CAN actually export the Azure app certificate and use it in Apache on a VM anywhere.

Here is how I did it.

Step1
Downloaded and installed OpenSSL tool for windows into this folder

> cd  "c:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin"

Step2
In Azure portal click on your certificate and select Export Certificate. 
Click the Download as certificate button and this will give you a CERTIFICATES.pfx file.
Save it into "c:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin"

Step3
Open a command prompt to convert the pfx to pem format with the following command:

```
>cd  "c:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin"
>openssl pkcs12 -in CERTIFICATES.pfx -out CERTIFICATES.pem -nodes
```

Step4
Download Notepad++ for windows and break this CERTIFICATES.pem into 3 files.

Make 3 copies and name them PRIVATE.key CHAIN.pem and PUBLIC.pem

```
PRIVATE.key
CHAIN.pem (will contain both certificates. My Azure ones were from GoDaddy)
PUBLIC.pem
```

Edit them and remove the certificates that you don't need from each one and keep the one you need.

Your private key text should look like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
"private hashed key inside here"
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The CHAIN key text should look like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
"GoDaddy Root Certificate Authority key in here"
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
"GoDaddy Secure Certificate Authority key in here"
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Your public key text should look like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
"public hashed key inside here"
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Step5
Copy these 3 resultant files to your Apache installation drive and modify the Apache httpd config file containing the SSL entries to point to the three new files as follows:

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/certs/PRIVATE.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/certs/CHAIN.pem"
SSLCertificateFile "C:/certs/PUBLIC.pem"
```

Done.

Comment: Hint: the password is empty so just hit enter when prompted!

Answer (score 0):

According to the author of this blog post (see comments), you can't use the certificate outside App Service, as in there's no way to export it.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/internals-of-app-service-certificate/

> *John • 8 months ago*
>   Is there any way to export the certificate as a PFX file?
>
> ***Ashish** • 8 months ago*
>   Thanks John ! No, currently certificates are tied to a subscription so you can only use it with App Service Apps in the subscription you use for creating App Service Certificate.

Comment: Do you have any idea if 'currently' means that someday they will be exportable?

Comment: No idea. Try opening a support case with App Service from the Portal, maybe you get more.

Comment: For this to be useful we really need these certs to be exportable to be used elsewhere, like VM, Cloud Service, etc.. Should be a broader Azure SSL service. Also price should match reality of LetsEncrypt and other lower cost SSL CAs, maybe Semantec etc have a monopoly on this? Maybe what they offer isn't worth what they've been charging.. maybe.

Comment: I believe this service is offered more for convenience rather than Microsoft trying to get into the business of selling certificates. At least that's how i see it being advertised.

Comment: You can now export certificates as PFX files. Use OpenSSL to convert them to PEM format if required using this command:                                                
 >openssl pkcs12 -in KEYVAULT.pfx -out CERTIFICATES.pem -nodes

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local PFX copy of the app service certificate and use it anywhere you want. You create the local copy using a PowerShell script.

Details are in this MSDN blog post.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/02/24/creating-a-local-pfx-copy-of-app-service-certificate/